# Configuring struts 2 to load on startup

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

My Struts 2 application currently loads resource when a request comes in for the resource(jsp,action). I what all resources needed, to be loaded once the application is first deployed unto the container to have fast response times. How can I accomplish this? [Note] I am using Tomcat as my Servlet Container.

Comment: It's difficult to tell you, without code nobody could understand your question. You should edit your post and add details.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to implement Filters... as Filter starts with the application once it loaded and it will probably be helpful in order to load the resources.

You can add up your code in init method as it will be initiated with the start of container.

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter
{


    public void init( FilterConfig config ) throws ServletException
    {
        System.out.println( "PUBLIC  Fileter Started." );
    }
    public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain )
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
//DO NOTHING
    }


}
```

And do add an entry in web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.filter.TestFilter</filter-class>


    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```